# Activity won't launch from notification when the app is started from notification

Tags: java, android

I have an app that sends notifications, and when clicked, opens an activity from my app. If you launch the app and keep the app open and click notifications, it works properly. However, when the app is closed, it doesn't. This is what happens:

Close app > receive notification > click notification > opens the correct activity > receive another notification > nothing happens when clicked

The intended functionality is for the notification to open the activity regardless if it is already open, and just add it onto the task stack. So if you clicked 3 notifications, the stack would be ActivityA > ActivityA > ActivityA. Here is the code for the notification:

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
notificationManager.notify(ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
  .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
  .setAutoCancel(true)
  .setCustomContentView(helper.createSmallView(context))
  .setCustomBigContentView(helper.createBigView(context))
  .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,
    new Intent(context, ActivityA.class),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
  )
  .build());
```

I also tried using a broadcast `PendingIntent`. The `BroadcastReceiver` would be called but the call to `Context#startActivity` did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.class, NewActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

PendingIntent
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
notificationManager.notify(ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
.setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setCustomContentView(helper.createSmallView(context))
.setCustomBigContentView(helper.createBigView(context))
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
.build());

Comment: Clearing the task stack is not the intended functionality. In the original post I explain how I want it to add to the task stack.